# DoxyWizrad "run" button is not enabled

Tags: doxygen

All directories exist, but the `Run` button is not enabled. What could I be doing wrongly?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can  I post any more to help you to help me?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using. As far as I can tell you didn't specify a doxygen settings file (`Doxyfile`) on startup and also didn't save the settings you made.

Comment: v 1.9.2 (latest is 1.9.5, but I doubt if that makes a difference). No, I did not specify a setting file, nor did I save my settings. I ought to be able to enter my settings manually first time. If they work - which they don't - then I will save them. I just don't understand what is going wrong here, DoxyWizard has worked just fine on other project s n the past

Comment: I don't think there won't be a lot differences for your problem between the 1.9.2 and 1.9.5 version. But probably the the reason lies in the reason I gave, maybe in the past you did do a save / start with a Doxyfile.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is no Doxygen config file in it's bin directory, nor in the source code directory. I am also not sure why it would make a difference, if I don't load it

Comment: To run doxygen a settings file is necessary, so from the wizard (when not starting with a settings file) one has to save the file to be able to run doxygen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe this remains an issue in version **1.10.0**. Fortunately, I've wrestled with this anew a few times before. You **MUST first save your configuration (doxygen settings file `Doxyfile`) to your "*working directory*"** BEFORE the '*Run doxygen*' button is enabled.